# How to create an "Edit Page" for a redux-form where we pass the existing data to the page

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have a redux-form which is used for data entry from the user(in my case the redux-form is used for recording posts in a blog).So,if I want to edit the existing data,then I want that the user will be redirected to the redux-form but the values of that particular post which the user want to edit should be passed along and the input fields in the redux-form should be populated with the existing data of the the post.So,now I am not able to figure out how to pass the data of the post to the redux-form and populate the redux-form from the beginning.My redux-form now has a function which is used in a **"Field"** from redux-form.The function looks like:

```
renderField(field) {
      return(
        <div className="title-design">
            <label className="label-design"> {field.label} </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="title-input"
              {...field.input}
            />
            <div className="text-help  has-danger">
              {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
            </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
```

And in my render method:

```
render() {
      const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            label="Title for Post"
            name="title"
            component={this.renderField}
          />

          <Field
            label="Post Content"
            name="body"
            component={this.renderField}
          />

          <Field
            label="Category"
            name="category"
            component={this.renderCategory}
            />


          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          <Link  to="/">
            <button className="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
          </Link>
        </form>
      );
    }
}
```

Also, can I use the same reudx-form which is used to create a new post, or do I have to create a new component only for editing the already existing posts? Can someone please help me with this.